# Use Non-Readonly property in GetHashCode with DataMember attribute

Tags: c#, wcf, equality

I use a **DataContract** to handle a class in a WCF-Service. Therefore I need the property **ApiCallStatus** (type: ApiCallStatus as Enum) to have a both auto-getter and -setter. But for the override of **GetHashCode** I need a "readonly" property to implement it correctly. Is there a way to implement this in a way that both requirements work correctly and are implemented in a clean way?

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiCallStatusInformation {
    [DataMember]
    public ApiCallStatus ApiCallStatus { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ApiCallStatusInformation other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return this.ApiCallStatus == other.ApiCallStatus;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        return obj.GetType() == this.GetType() && this.Equals((ApiCallStatusInformation) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return (int) this.ApiCallStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make the setter private, and it will still work as a `DataMember`. BTW, rather than casting to an int, you should do `return this.ApiCallStatus.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for your help. I use ReSharper and the warning still exists if I make the setter private. Can I safely ignore this warning now?

Comment: You can even make it readonly and private - that should fix the warning!

Comment: @MatthewWatson It works. Thanks a lot. You may post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `[DataMember]` may be `private readonly`, which avoids this issue.

The reason it can be `private readonly` is that the `[DataContract]` implementation uses reflection to set the `[DataMember]` fields, which means that the `private` and `readonly` aspects are ignored.